# Unable to run eclipse goal using mvn-ant-task

Tags: maven, ant

I am trying to run `eclipse:eclipse` on a maven project from an ant build file.

But its failing with error:

```
    Eclipsify:
     [echo] Converting Maven Project to Eclipse Project
[artifact:mvn] -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory system propery is not set. Check $M2_HOME environment variable and mvn script match.org.apache.tools.ant.ExitExceptio
n: Permission ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "exitVM") was not granted.
[artifact:mvn]  at org.apache.tools.ant.types.Permissions$MySM.checkExit(Permissions.java:194)
[artifact:mvn]  at java.lang.Runtime.exit(Runtime.java:107)
[artifact:mvn]  at java.lang.System.exit(System.java:962)
```

Below are the configurations in my build.xml

```
<project name="ConnectAll"
     default="default"
     xmlns:artifact="antlib:org.apache.maven.artifact.ant">
```

And in the ant target I have added eclipse goal as given below

```
<artifact:mvn pom="${pom}" mavenhome="${MVN_HOME}">
            <arg value="eclipse:eclipse" />
            <arg value="-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=true"/>
</artifact:mvn>
```

Also i have verified that the `${MVN_HOME}` property and the actual `M2_HOME` are same.

Can someone help me figure out what am I missing here.

Comment: Which Eclipse version are you using?

Comment: Describe what you try to achieve. Starting point and goal. Which makes it easier to understand what you try to achieve. Instead of just solving some technical issue.

Comment: I have some maven projects in scm, i wanted to checkout those project and run eclipse:eclipse to convert the maven projects in to eclipse projects . similar to `$project_home: mvn eclipse:eclipse` command

Comment: Eclipse version am using is `Mars Release (4.5.0)`

Comment: You should simply import those project into Eclipse Mars that's it...no need for eclipse:eclipse...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Eclipse Juno (v4.2) it contains Maven integration.

Maven projects should be imported using the import wizard:

- Eclipse Menu: *File -> Import...*
- The dialog *Import*, on the page *Select* opens
- Select from tree select *Maven -> Existing Maven Projects*
- Press the button *Next*
- The page *Maven Projects* opens
- Fill in the field *Root Directory*, with the location where the Maven project(s) are located (Use the button *Browse...* to easliy select the location (This will show a selection window, when pressing OK, or seleecting a directory, it can take a while, before all the Maven projects are fuond, as all underlaying directories are scanned))
- From the *Projects* view select the project you like to import (project which already have been imported, are shown in gray (not selectable). This can also happen if different Maven project / modules do have the same artifactid. As the Maven artifactid, is used as the Eclipse project name).
- Press the button *Finish*, to start importing the selected Maven projects
  **Warning** This will take a while, as many times, lost of dependencies need to be downloaded as well.

**Remark** Never use the `mvn eclipse:eclipse`, when using Eclipse with integrated Maven support, as these conflict with each other.

Comment: I generally prefer using the Eclipse Maven integration for importing, but unfortunately since am working on some legacy projects the classpath is not set properly when i load the project with "Import existing maven projects". So am forced to use the eclipse:eclipse command line option and "Import using existing project"

Comment: What is the issue with the classpath then? The classpath should be build up by Maven correctly. Better correct that, then using mvn eclipse:eclipse

Comment: Or verify the Eclipse configuration file .classpath, that mvn eclipse:eclipse generates, with the one that is created by the Eclipse Maven import wizard.